# Export Dialogflow History?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Really, I just want to be able to filter the history logs in Dialogflow for specific intents. But seeing as there is no search bar or anything that can help, is there any way I can export these logs to an excel sheet or something? That way I can filter the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Dialogflow website nor API provide such option.

Recently a new option in Dialogflow console appeared. You can find "Log interactions to Google Cloud" in agent Settings (General tab). This will enable logging of user interactions to Stackdriver. There you can filter the logs and export them to other Google cloud services - BigQuery, Cloud Storage and Cloud Pub/Sub.

Keep in mind that there is an additional pricing for using Stackdriver logging.